# Hide Input Field data on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, form-submit

I've got a login form with two input fields: username and password.

```
<form method="post" action="testPwd.html">
<p>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" maxlength="30"></p>
<p>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password" maxlength="25"></p>

<p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Enter">
</p>

</form>
```

Once the user submits the form, his username and password are shown in the browser's network attribute in form data section

Request URL: http://localhost:8090/test/testPwd.html
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily

username: admin
password: admin

I don't want his username and password to be on display.

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean in the developer tools of the browser?

Comment: Yes , developer tools

Comment: use request.getParameter("username");

Comment: You can't do that

Answer (score 0):

That is an expected behavior. You can always see what parameters are passed to POST method (or any method for that matter)

However, you do not want the inputs to be readable to *normal* human eye, you can encode the username and password before passing them to the API and decode at the server side before using them.

Below is a very simple example. It does not guarantee anything but it will make the values not readable.

```
var encodedUsername = window.btoa(username); // encode username
var encodedPassword= window.btoa(password); // encode a password   

var decodedUsername = window.atob(encodedUsername); // decode username
var decodedPassword = window.atob(encodedPassword); // decode password
```